# How to do exact word match in Neo4j?

Tags: php, regex, neo4j, exact-match

In Neo4j, we can do mysql query **"like"** with

ex.
If node **"temp"** have column **"col"** and value "This was in World war 1945";

If we search by "wor"

and where query is

```
temp.col =~  '(?i).*'. $search_value . '.*'
```

Then results are coming. But I want results to come only when searched for world with any case change.

How to do exact word match?

i.e. If we search for string then there should be space or no any character at start and end of word.

Comment: "(?i)" is used in Neo4j for case in-sensative matching. ".*" used as "%" in Mysql. I want to do exact word match in strings and not sub-strings. @nhahtdh

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing: When you search by `wor`, you want `world` to turn up as a result?

Comment: I said when I search by "wor" result should not come. But when I search by "world" result should come. @nhahtdh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=~ '(?i).*'. $search_value . '.*'
```

=~            = Regex search
(?i)          = case insenstive
.*            = Match anything
$search_value = Your string
.*            = Match anything

If you want to match whole words, and you want to match the case, and if that whole word can appear mid sentence then you could try:

```
=~'.*\\b' . $search_value . '\\b.*'
```

`\b` is a word boundary matcher.

Update: `"\\b"` double slashes are required to [escaping in for regular expressions](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-where.html#where-escaping-in-regular-expressions).

Comment: Sure @nhahtdh, I can see that, but where is the query going to be run?

Comment: Regardless of where the query is going to be run, the string literal is parsed at PHP. The next level will be parsed at the regex engine.

Comment: You may be right, but I believe that the concatenated string will be passed by Rest to Neo. and that String should be '=~.*\\bVALUE\\b.*' where it can then be parsed by the Java based query parser. Happy to be wrong, in which case, use `=~'.*\b' . $search_value . '\b.*'`

Comment: I don't think the solution is wrong. Just saying "java string parser" is wrong, since the literal is parsed at PHP (I assume due to the syntax), before it is pushed elsewhere.

Comment: @nhahtdh :) Maybe you're right, it definitely is PHP, the question says so! My point was that the JVM that parses the concatenated String might require double slashes, but given it has come over HTTP to get there in the first place, it is probably unnecessary. It's gone..

Comment: A bit off tangent here, but in a Java program, the JVM doesn't parse the String literal. The compiler has already done it when the program is compiled into bytecode.

Comment: You're quite right @nhahtdh, that's why I have removed the offending code and thanks for pointing out.

Comment: In my case "\\b" worked and "\b" not worked. Thanks for pointing to good answer @JohnMark13

Comment: @SomnathMuluk: http://ideone.com/X5xvb5 Both should work if you use single quoted string literal.

Comment: @nhahtdh : I tried both queries in Neo4j parser. Results are coming only for double slashes. http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-where.html#where-escaping-in-regular-expressions . I think Neo4j require to escape out string to work for slashes.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk: Not sure whether your code is run from PHP, but if that is not the case, then the rule for string literal parsing can be different, which leads to difference in the result.